# Python request.get not working on url = 'https: // www.cnb.cz' webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I tried to get string from:

```
url = "https: // www.cnb.cz / cs / financni - trhy / devizovy - trh / kurzy - devizoveho - trhu / kurzy - devizoveho - trhu / rok.txt?rok = 2023".
```

However, it does not get access to the page. It turns:

```
Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 445, in prepare_url raise InvalidURL(f"Invalid URL {url!r}: No host supplied") requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Invalid URL 'https: // www.cnb.cz / cs / financni - trhy / devizovy - trh / kurzy - devizoveho - trhu / kurzy - devizoveho - trhu / rok.txt?rok = 2023': No host supplied
```

I tried:

```
HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url,headers=HEADERS, verify=False)
```

I tried also the https://www.cnb.cz/cs/ without success. It seems that this page does not accept the request.

Comment: Why do you have all those spaces in the URL?  The first three make the URL invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The url you're trying is incorrect, too many spaces.

Here's a way to fix that:

```
import re
import requests

url = re.sub(" ", "", url)
print(url)

requests.get(url)
```

Output:

```
https://www.cnb.cz/cs/financni-trhy/devizovy-trh/kurzy-devizoveho-trhu/kurzy-devizoveho-trhu/rok.txt?rok=2023

<Response [200]>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.cnb.cz/cs/financni-trhy/devizovy-trh/kurzy-devizoveho-trhu/kurzy-devizoveho-trhu/rok.txt?rok=2023'

page = requests.get(url).content

print(page)
```